# How to add numbers in an array, and re-evaluate and add numbers when more are added to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add numbers in an array and update the DOM with the added numbers. Then when more numbers are added to the array, when the addition function is run again, the array is re-evaluated and the DOM updated with what the numbers add up to in the array.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scu67aou/2/

Currently, it is only displaying the last number in the array, and not adding what is in the array. Thanks for any help.

JavaScript:

```
var numb = [];
var total = '';

$('.new').on('click', function(){
    var infoStuff = $('.to-add input').val();
    $('.added').append('<div class="test">'+ infoStuff + '</div>');
    numb.push(infoStuff);
});

$('.button').on('click', function(){
    for(var i=0; i < numb.length; i++){
        total = Number(numb[i]);
    }
    $('.total').html(total);
});
```

Comment: What if i space separate numbers in the input? You'll have `4 5 89`in single array location, for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the new values to `total` inside the loop, rather than assigning the new value to it. Also, declare `total` as a local variable - otherwise the new numbers will be added to the total of previous calculation:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
  var total=0; // local variable, starts with 0 every time
  for (var i = 0; i < numb.length; i++) {
    total += Number(numb[i]); // add the number to existing total
  }
  $('.total').html(total);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scu67aou/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t8htbo5u/3/

```
var numb = [];

$('.new').on('click', function(){
        var infoStuff = $('.to-add input').val();
        $('.added').append('<div class="test">'+ infoStuff + '</div>');
        numb.push(parseInt(infoStuff));
});

$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('.total').html(numb.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        return prev + curr;
    }, 0));
});
```

I used [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and ran `parseInt` on your `infoStuff` before adding it to `numb` for the sake of the example, you can change that it you want to take decimals.

Comment: Note that Array.reduce() isn't supported on some of the older browsers, so you'd need to polyfill for them.

Comment: @Chipe that is true, you might want to consider a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) just in case